# Can I prevent a package from importing specific other packages in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Does Java, or eclipse (or an eclipse plugin) have a feature to prevent one package namespace from using another when the code is all located within the same Java project, regardless of public class visibility?

e.g. package "myapp.model" may never import from "myapp.fxview"

**Background**

I am writing an application using a "Model View Controller" architechture in Java using eclipse.

"myapp.model" contains pure Java code, no external libraries or platform specific code
"myapp.fxview" contains a classes overriding JavaFX classes

I want to ensure that my Model code does not become "contaminated" with dependencies to the View code (for example accidentallly using an enum from the "view" implementation in my Model) so that I can use my Model accross multiple platforms (JavaFX PC, Android, WebServer Backend)

I would like to keep all my code in one project to minimise time messing around with project / workspace setup issues. (I am aware taht this "issue" would be easy to resolve using seperate projects)

Comment: Short answer: yes (at least Eclipse had something like that). Unfortunately I don't know where exactly this is located off the top of my head. However, I'd not rely on Eclipse for that. One other thing I could think of: maybe the Java module system could help here (I'd have to have another look at it).

Comment: You can split your code in projects and then specify so-called _access rules_: in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Projects_ select the subnode _Access rules_ of a required project and click _Edit..._

Comment: When you write code in `myapp.model`, just don't write any import statements for `my app.fxview`.   You have to explicitly import classes from another package if you want to use them, if you don't explicitly import the classes, then you are prevented from using them (unless you resort to dynamic techniques like reflection).

Comment: Thomas, thanks. The other two please read the question. I very explicitely stated that I was not interested in the options you presented. Both of the options you mentioned have major pitfalls on larger projects. I currently have a project on Java 8 at work with over 300 sub projects. 7 software developers have been able to accidentally contribute to dependancy hell thanks to those methods.

Comment: I did read your question and disagree that you explicitly stated in the question that what I suggested was not appropriate for you. Anyway it is a public space and the suggestion may still help others who may not need the added complexity of a module system.  You may wish to investigate the [encapsulation capabilities of the Java module system](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity) as proposed in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the Modules system available in Java 9 or newer. There are module declerations such as "exports...to",  or "opens...to". By using these you can specifically restrict which packages are available where. To support this, better restructure the package names to represent that there may be multiple views (myapp.fxview -> myapp.view.fx).

This **untested** code shows roughly how this would look

```
module modelmodule {
    exports myapp.model to myapp.view.fx;
    exports myapp.model to myapp.application;
}

module viewmodule {
    exports myapp.view.fx to myapp.application;
}
```

@see https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html

Thanks to Thomas in the comments for pointing me in the correct direction. I have been using Java 8 at work and as such stuck to the same at home. Hence, I had no idea of the Modules system until now.